# why child components div in react is not re rendering even though child component re renders at state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

[image: post clicked on complete button][image]I have 2 componets app.js and layput.js . In app.js I have todo state which will have JSON Object which gets added when Add button from app.js is clicked. In layout.js using .map function have printed the object passed as prop from app.js. there are 2 buttons in layout.js which are deleting and updating json value where delete button works properly and re renders child component but update button is not working even though layout.js is getting re renders

```
app.js
import './App.css';
import Layout from './pages/layout';
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
function App() {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState([]);
  const titleRef = useRef();
  const todoRef = useRef();
  let refid=useRef(0);
  console.log("render in app",refid);
  function Addtodo() {
    setTodo([...todo, { id:refid.current++,title: titleRef.current.value, todo: todoRef.current.value, isComplete: false }]);
  }
  function deleteTodo(title) {
    setTodo(todo.filter(filterItem => filterItem.title !== title));
  }
  function updateTodo(title) {
    let newtodo=todo;
    for (let i=0;i<todo.length;i++ )
    {
      if (todo[i].title === title && !todo[i].isComplete) {        
        todo[i].isComplete = true;
        todo[i].todo=todo[i].todo+'1';
      }
    }    
      setTodo(todo);      
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Title
      <input ref={titleRef} id="title" type="text" />
      To Do
      <input ref={todoRef} id="todo" type="text" />
      <button type="button" onClick={Addtodo}>Add</button>
      <Layout todoArray={todo} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} updateTodo={updateTodo} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
layout.js
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
function Layout(props) {
    const ondelete = (e) => {
        props.deleteTodo(e.target.name);
    }
    const onupdate = (e) => {        
        props.updateTodo(e.target.name);
    }
console.log('props',props.todoArray);
    return (<>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        {props.todoArray.map((todos) => {
            return <div key={todos.id}>
                <span><b> Title :</b> {todos.title}</span>
                <span><b> To Do :</b> {todos.todo}</span>
                <span><b> Is Complete :</b> {todos.isComplete.toString()}</span>
                <button name={todos.title} onClick={onupdate}>Complete</button>
                <button name={todos.title} onClick={ondelete}>Delete</button>
            </div>
        })}
    </>);
}

export default Layout;
```

i want print tag Is Complete to True if we clicked on Complete Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses shallow comparison for prop changes, this means that if the `todoArray` prop is passed the same object reference, it will not re-render, even if the array elements have changes.

The solution is to call `setTodo` with a new array every time.

We can ensure that a new array is created, instead of modifying the old array, by spreading the old array into your `newTodo` var.

```js
  function updateTodo(title) {
    let newtodo = [...todo];
    for (let i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
      if (todo[i].title === title && !todo[i].isComplete) {
        todo[i].isComplete = true;
        todo[i].todo = todo[i].todo + '1';
      }
    } setTodo(todo);
  }
```

Comment: thank you , it worked but need to understand why it worked? We have assigned a value to **newtodo** and use `setTodo(newtodo)` but inside for loop we have change the value of **todo**

Comment: @GirishZope, notice this syntax `[...todo]` This is the spread operator, it creates a new array with the elements from `todo`. Then we call `setTodo(newTodo)`. React compares the previous value of todo to the new value of todo and finds that they are not the same array. Therefore, Reach will re-render the component.